# jQuery to remove an old GA sccript tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I've been trying to come up with a script to remove an old GA script tag on old pages of a site, there are few thousand pages that I need it to be removed from.

Looking for the best option using jQuery.

I'm trying to remove the script based on this value UA-27179278-1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27179278-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

I've tried working with .contains() and .remove() to either remove the script as a whole or just the GA ID so it stops tracking.

I'm not sure if I can remove just the var and that would solve the issue

The  is within the body tag further down the page with in a class called bottom_bucket and not in the head section, if we place the jQuery code for removal in the head would the page hit that first?

Looking for advice or pointers into the best solution

Comment: Using jQuery is not going to help..... By the time jQuery can access it, that script would have run.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be as follows

```js
$(function() {
    console.log($("#Google").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var foundGA = $("#Google").text();
    
    var oldCode = 'UA-27179278-1';
    var newCode = 'Text';
    
    $("#Google").text(foundGA.replace(oldCode, newCode));
 
});
</script>

<script id="Google" type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27179278-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Provided that he executed the code before that of Analytics is executed